# Material-ui color of components is only primary and secondary

Tags: material-ui

```
<Button variant="contained" color="success">save</Button>
<Button variant="contained" color="error">delete</Button>
```

Both buttons show the `default` color.

Most components behave the same way: `success`, `info`... none of them work as I expect them to.

I know this is not a bug, according to the API documentation, MaterialUI's components simply don’t recognize other palette's colors at all, but this bugs me.

Why components only recognize `primary` and `secondary` colors?

How should I use the colors of my `theme.palette` so that they are applied to my components?

Is changing the theme my only option to achieve the effect I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`Button` API documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/button/), the accepted values for the `color` prop are `'default'`, `'inherit'`, `'primary'` and `'secondary'` only. Therefore, Material UI will not recognize `color='success'` nor `color='error'` and show the corresponding colors.

I assume you are trying to use the `success` and `error` colors from the [default theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/#default-theme). In the default theme object, the colors for `success` and `error` can be found in `theme.palette.success` and `theme.palette.error` respectively.

Therefore, we can access the default theme colors using the following way:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  success: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.success.main
  },
  error: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.error.main
  }
}));

export default function ContainedButtons() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="contained" classes={{ root: classes.success }}>
        Save
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" classes={{ root: classes.error }}>
        Delete
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Save & Delete buttons]

[image: Edit on Code Sandbox]